# How to find first hidden parent of an element and make it visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I want to find the first hidden parents of an element in order to make it visible.

I tried this without success:

```
$('input[name="toto"]').parents(":hidden:first").show();
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Surely you want to find *all* hidden ancestors to make the descendant element visible? Otherwise it'll remain hidden unless you recursively call the same function/approach for *every* other 'first hidden parents.'

Comment: hello not all the ancestors only the first hidden which is the one who hide the current element, but the is others hidden ancestor (pagination) that i don't want to show, so i realy need to find the first hidden parent

Answer (score 1):

Why not just `.show()` *all* ancestor elements that are hidden:

```
$('input[name="toto"]').parents(":hidden").show();
```

In fact, why waste time filtering out the `:hidden` ancestors, when you could just `show()` all of them?:

```
$('input[name="toto"]').parents().show();
```

Comment: hello, because I only want to show the element within a hidden parent's div and there is others hidden ancester that have to stay hidden

Comment: A hidden ancestor can't have a visible child.